# Javascript - variable visibility

Tags: javascript

Hi I have following code

```
var idx = 0;
var size = 0;
do {
    response.push({
        key: "data" + idx,
        ajaxOptions: function () {
            var data = this.getPref("groupsCN");
            var items = data.split(';');
            size = items.length;
            idx++;
            alert('inside index: ' + idx + ' < inside length ' + size);
            return {
                url: '/rest/adrestresource/1.0/activedirectory/findgroups&test@lab.local&Bezhesla1&localhost&',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml"
            }
        }
    });
    alert('outside index: ' + idx + ' < outside length ' + size);
} while (idx < size);
```

The function `getPref` loads string with some values divided by `;`. Main point is to iterate through all this values and do something with them. But following code outputs

> outside index: 0 < outside length: 0

so it means that variables `idx` and `size` are not modified inside the function. But I don't know why?

I must call `this.getPref()` inside `ajaxOptions -> function`, because it doesn't work outside of it (I don't know why, this function is part of Atlassian gadget JavaScript framework)

Comment: Was there a reason you put so much spaces on the left side of your code? Properly formatted code is easier to read IMO.

Comment: You never call the function that sets `idx` or `size`.

Comment: sry, i copypasted code from my IDE, and it got messed up

Comment: what does getPref return ? Have you make sure data actually contains strings before splitting it ?

Comment: It's not clear what `response.push` is doing, but presumably, the function you pass to `ajaxOptions` is being called in a callback, if at all. `idx` and `size` are modified within the function but the `alert` is called before the callback.

Comment: getPref returns string, which contains values divided by ';'. Yeah i checked that data returned from getPref are valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not *executing* a function, you are just *assigning* anonymous function to an object literal's property `ajaxOptions`. To execute a function use something like this:

```
var idx = 0;
var size = 0;
do {
    response.push({
        key: "data" + idx,
        ajaxOptions: (function () {
            var data = this.getPref("groupsCN");
            var items = data.split(';');
            size = items.length;
            idx++;
            alert('inside index: ' + idx + ' < inside length ' + size);
            return {
                url: '/rest/adrestresource/1.0/activedirectory/findgroups&test@lab.local&Bezhesla1&localhost&',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml"
            }
        })()
    });
    alert('outside index: ' + idx + ' < outside length ' + size);
} while (idx < size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
var idx = 0; var size = 0; var self = this;
```

and

```
var data = function () { return self.getPref("groupsCN"); };
```

Comment: This is the third or fourth time I'm saying this same thing: **don't quote your own text.** Don't put the `>` marks in front of text that isn't a direct quote **from somewhere else**. Do you understand what I'm trying to say?